# Is TreeSet based on key and value?

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I was reading about the tree set which is part of the Java collections framework. I am stuck with the aspect if tree set stores its elements in the form  pairs?

Comment: TreeSet is not based on key and value. TreeMap is

Comment: TreeSet: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

TreeMap: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Answer (score 2):

TreeSet's API is in terms of Comparable objects, but under the hood it uses a TreeMap where every key-value-pair has the same dummy object PRESENT. Looking in [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeSet.java), this is:

```
// Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
    private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
```

For example, add is implemented as:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
        return m.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Maps require uniqueness on keys, so they are simply more general versions of sets and have all of the necessary machinery. But we only need one half of the map, the keys, and can replace varying values with a single dummy value.

Comment: Thank you so much for that !! You have mentioned in your explanation add is implemented as follows. But in most of the code I really don't see that method except for Linkedlist. Is that done internally ?